# Running Oracle SQL scripts with Ansible playbook

Tags: oracle, ansible, ansible-galaxy

A look at the core database modules in Ansible [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_database_modules.html#) shows no signs of a module for Oracle. What is the best way to handle SQL/PLSQL deployments via Ansible for Oracle databases?

Are we expected to use roles from [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles?page=1&page_size=10&tags=database&autocomplete=oracle) to handle this? Very few people seem to have downloaded roles listed on Galaxy for Oracle.

Comment: When you say "SQL scripts" do you mean large SQL*Plus scripts, or just random SQL and PL/SQL commands?  If you're looking for a way to automate plain SQL and PL/SQL commands you may want to look at my open source program [Method5](https://method5.github.io/).  It's an agentless, parallel remote execution program; sort of like Ansible, but it's designed specifically for Oracle databases.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I am specifically looking for Ansible here.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a role to install apex 5 (where I first uninstall apex 4). I use modules like 'script' and 'shell'. I am not too happy about environment initialization but I am still learning. For any SQL/PLSQL task, sqlplus is the right tool. (perhaps SQLcl can do better..?)

```
- name: Determine apex version
  become: yes
  become_user: oracle
  shell: source /etc/profile &&  sqlplus -S / as sysdba @"{{ temp_dir }}/apexver.sql"
  register: apexver
  args:
     executable: /bin/bash
  changed_when: "'APEX_040000' in apexver.stdout"

- name: oracle apex remove
  become: yes
  become_user: oracle
  script: apex_remove.sh {{ item }} 
  with_items: 
    - 'XE'
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: result
  when: "'APEX_040000' in apexver.stdout"

22:18 $ cat apex_remove.sh
#!/bin/sh

# set oracle environment
. /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh
ORACLE_SID=$1

sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
connect / as sysdba
@?/apex/apxremov.sql
exit
EOF
```

Comment: I am wondering why wouldn't Ansible give a module for Oracle DB

Comment: Well because nobody have written one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is related to your question, but I originally was looking for Ansible modules to Start/Stop and get the Status of an Oracle database. I couldn't find anything suitable so I wrote my own ansible modules. Modules give you the power to define a standard interface, with OK/Failed/Changed responses to tasks, while performing as much low-level activity/commands as you need (in this way they are much more flexible than the simple shell/command modules). I wrote the modules to be idempotent -- they won't attempt to start databases that are already started, and won't attempt to stop databases that are already stopped. And if a stop/stop function isn't successful, it returns Failed with stdout/stderr.

Along with Oracle databases, I've also written modules to provide interfaces for Business Objects and Weblogic services. The modules are significant up-front work, but once they are stable they can be used in a wide range of playbooks.

I haven't looked at Galaxy to see if there is anything else like this, and unfortunately due to the nature of my client/contract I'm not sure that I can share the modules that we have developed. I just thought I'd offer this as a possible avenue for you to explore.