# Can we execute PLSQL programs in ansible ? If we can, how?

Tags: ansible

PLSQL program execution in asnible ? is there any modules to execute to plsql programs in ansible

Answer (score 0):

I'm absolutely not an oracle expert. But I recently worked with a team that had a project with an oracle database in their stack and helped them automating their deployment (mainly initializing dbs with bootstrap data on fresh deployment of their websphere application).

As you will see on the [ansible database modules page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_database_modules.html), ansible does not (yet...?) provide any module to interact with oracle databases.

What we ended up doing for the project was installing sqlplus on the ansible control machine and other needed hosts, put the plsql scripts under version control as files or templates in our ansible git repo, copy the scripts where needed and play them running sqlplus through shell/command module.

There is [an other SO question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41341823/running-oracle-sql-scripts-with-ansible-playbook) (with no upvoted/accepted answer at this time) where you may find more valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for postgresql

```
- postgresql_query:
  db: my_db
  query: >
     do 
     $$ 
     declare
       k int;
     begin 
       select 123 into k;
     end;
     $$;
```